# Symmetry breaking with Lagrangian

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, symmetry-breaking

I have been studying the spontaneous symmetry braking from [Zee](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691140340) (Quantum Field theory ) and found in the page 224, he wrote the lagrangian as
$$\mathcal{L}=
\frac{1}{2}\{
λ
(∂φ)^2 + μ^2φ^ 2\} − \frac{\lambda}{4}(φ^4)$$

But according to sclar field theory  I got from Ryder 
$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\{
λ
(∂φ)^2 + μ^2φ^ 2\} − \frac{\lambda}{4!}(φ^4)$$
**Am I doing wrong?**

My another question is, the potential we have inserted in the Lagrangian is look like Mexican hat. What conditions will change the shape of the potential?
Symmetry breaking means ,**changing the Lagrangian with kinetic energy terms?**

Comment: Related-but-distinct: [What is the role of the vacuum expectation value in symmetry breaking and the generation of mass?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43714/9290)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the two is in the potential term (Ryder divides by 4! whereas Zee divides by 4). The physics doesn't change, provided the potential term has a nonzero minima. Really, that's where spontaneous symmetry breaking happens for a scalar field.

You have your Lagrangian
$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\partial^{\mu}\varphi\partial_{\mu}\varphi-\mu^{2}\varphi^{2}\right)-V(\varphi).
$$
If it has a nonzero vacuum energy, then $V(\varphi)\not=0$ for any $\varphi$. If this happens, it breaks symmetry since the vacuum is nonunique (egads!).

We find this happening if $\varphi_{0}$ satisfies $V'(\varphi_{0})=0$ but $V(\varphi_{0})\not=0$.

**Addendum:** The potential $V(\varphi)=c_{1}\varphi^{2}+c_{2}\varphi^{4}$ *would* experience spontaneous symmetry breaking, for nonzero constants $c_{1}$, $c_{2}$...but if $c_{1}=0$ -- as your model has -- there is no symmetry breaking.

Comment: How will I write in factorial form? I mean !.

Comment: @UnlimitedDreamer beg pardon? I don't quite understand your question...

Comment: I meant why two different authors choice two different potential? Arbitrary choosing wouldn't be a problem?

Comment: @UnlimitedDreamer Oh, well, the difference is purely mathematical and doesn't impact the physics. And in either case, there's no symmetry breaking until you add another term to the potential.