# When particles are collided some new particles come into existence. Is the field of the new particle was there before just not vibrating?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

I know that when two particles are collided some new particles come into existence and i know that the new particles weren't inside of the original particles. I understand  that the energy of the collision can vibrate other fields to make particles.

What I don't understand is "were those other fields nearby the collision site when the collision happen?"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "were those other fields nearby".

Comment: Mathematically, the field of the new particle always exits, as we always start with an action containing all the fields interested. Before collision, the new field is "dormant". It is in the ground state and vibrating, just like the harmonic oscillator. Physically, the new field should always exist, too. It is really difficult to imagine there is nothing new before collision and after collision, something just pops out.

Comment: @DrakeMarquis Thank you for your answer Mr. Marquis. But i believe i read that every field has "0" value in empty space except Higgs field. Isn't it means only Higgs field exists in empty space? Or something else.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Oh, sorry for my english. What i mean by that is: do those other fields exist before the collision, nearby the collision site?

Comment: @Tuna I never read a statement that each field has 0 value in empty space except Higgs field. Would you please provide the reference?

Comment: @DrakeMarquis It is the vacuum expectation value of the fields that are zero, except for the Higgs. see this  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43714/what-is-the-role-of-the-vacuum-expectation-value-in-symmetry-breaking-and-the-ge

Comment: @DrakeMarquis I read that statement again and i just realised it meant something else. "We can see that the lowest energy state appears when the Higgs fields energy value is not zero. When the space is empty, it is filled with a Higgs field." That means something else i guess. Pg. 196 Supersymmetry by Gordon Kane

Comment: @Tuna Yes, it means something else. Under certain conditions, the ground state of the Higgs field happens while the Higgs field is nonzero. In this case, the space is empty, meaningly, there is no matter, but the Higgs field fills the space.

Comment: @Tuna Glad to be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume you are talking about Quantum Fields. Particles are basically disturbances in fields. When particles collide, they can release energy. This agitates quantum fields, leading to a particle. (The disturbance in the field is the particle). There is a new disturbance in the field, and so, a new particle is created.

These fields exist and permeate through the entire universe, and you can find these fields even in a pure vacuum. In other words, quantum fields exist everywhere in the universe.

So, yes, there are fields near the collision site, as the collision site and its surroundings are parts of the universe. The fields will exist before, during, and after the collision.

Answer (score 2):

Think of tangled up wires on top of each other. Sometimes when you move one of them the right way it moves the other. Now let us say this movement is a vibration. You vibrate one and it vibrates the other. This is a cartoon picture of the mathematics.  A disturbance in some field (particle A) can cause a disturbance in another field (particle B appearing seemingly from nowhere). At least according to the math.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that when two particles are collided some new particles come into existence and i know that the new particles weren't inside of the original particles.

Yes, there is extensive experimental evidence for this.

> I understand that the energy of the collision can vibrate other fields to make particles.

The [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics which describes with great accuracy the collision and predicts the future behavior  is a mathematical model based on [quantum field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory).

Each elementary  particle in [the table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg) is assumed to be a field permeating all space, *like a coordinate system.* This field is mathematically represented at each (x,y,z,t) by the *free particle* solution of the corresponding equation,(Dirac for fermions for example). On these solutions creation operators ( differential operators) create a particle and annihilation operators destroy it. In this way a propagation, a "track" for an elementary particle can be envisaged, using [wave packets](https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node7.html) with the appropriate energy and momentum and [heisenberg uncertainty](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/uncer.html).

When two particles interact, the theory has specific rules which were developed to fit and predict  the data, and are simply described  for calculational purposes by the use of [Feynman diagrams](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html).

The energy of collision can allow creation operators to work on the underlying fields and create new particles which will propagate away  from the collision, as long as energy, momentum, angular momentum and all quantum numbers that have to be conserved are respected.

Not *vibrations*, but *[creation and annihilation operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_and_annihilation_operators)* acting on underlying all permeating fields is the mathematical model which succeeds to describe the data.